# Cant find the error in Heroku Logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services

I am doing the One Month Rails course and i get stucked in one point.

I have my app in Heroku: http://arcane-shelf-3404.herokuapp.com/

But when i upload an image, it give me an error.

Help me to find the error. Thanks!

Here is my log:

```
←[36m2014-06-02T06:19:47.681565+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: convert '/tmp/f
85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1s8hujo.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "
100x100>" '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1s8hujo20140602-2-1rj
ixun'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:19:47.955359+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: file -b --mime
'/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1s8hujo20140602-2-1rjixun'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:19:48.191298+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Ser
ver Error in 2818ms
←[33m2014-06-02T06:19:48.276690+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=POST pa
th=/pins host=arcane-shelf-3404.herokuapp.com request_id=aa625159-c846-4e33-b931
-be0ed643437a fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3937ms status
=500 bytes=1754
←[36m2014-06-02T06:19:48.211023+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-06-02T06:19:48.176176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [paperclip] saving /pins/i
mages/000/000/003/original/GDT05_camera_lens3.png
←[36m2014-06-02T06:19:48.211031+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/pins_con
troller.rb:22:in `create'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:19:48.211028+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ArgumentError (missing req
uired :bucket option):
←[36m2014-06-02T06:19:48.211032+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-06-02T06:19:48.211033+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:06.259776+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up t
o starting
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133404+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-06-02 06:21:10] FATA
L SignalException: SIGTERM
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133409+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133414+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133433+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133411+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133435+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133436+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133444+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133446+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   bin/rails:4:in `require'

←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133412+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/l
ib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133448+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133493+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-06-02 06:21:10] INFO
  going to shutdown ...
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133442+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-06-02 06:21:10] INFO
  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133706+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133443+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_comman
d!'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133440+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.133438+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in s
erver'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:10.346377+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c
ommand `bin/rails server -p 50269 -e production`
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:09.495879+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping all processes
with SIGTERM
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:11.476607+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
tus 143
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:17.901730+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
ting to up
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:17.802200+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-06-02 06:21:17] INFO
  WEBrick 1.3.1
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:17.802319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-06-02 06:21:17] INFO
  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:17.802903+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-06-02 06:21:17] INFO
  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=50269
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.273758+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Rails 4.1.1 application
 starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:50269
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.273760+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Run `rails server -h` f
or more startup options
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.273751+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Booting WEBrick
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.273762+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Notice: server is liste
ning on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.273763+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Ctrl-C to shutdown serv
er
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.273765+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started POST "/pins" for 1
90.114.248.109 at 2014-06-02 06:21:19 +0000
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.379258+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#create as HTML
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.379355+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"??
?", "authenticity_token"=>"EMnpdVv9KK1Sz/kCL9X21W+6mfepM8/D+QFelQvmXXM=", "pin"=
>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbb4ee7c4d8 @tempfile=#<Tem
pfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140602-2-1hvrs94>, @original_filename="GDT05_camera le
ns3.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; n
ame=\"pin[image]\"; filename=\"GDT05_camera lens3.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/p
ng\r\n">, "description"=>"asdadad"}, "commit"=>"Create Pin"}
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.466196+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1
lj566b.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.707875+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.525316+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.593996+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:19.831975+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: convert '/tmp/f
85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "
300x300>" '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b20140602-2-qn5
wzi'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:20.409313+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: file -b --mime
'/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b20140602-2-qn5wzi'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:20.654060+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:20.542819+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1
lj566b.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:20.767431+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:20.842459+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:20.913966+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: convert '/tmp/f
85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "
100x100>" '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b20140602-2-kzm
tux'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:21.199779+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: file -b --mime
'/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-1lj566b20140602-2-kzmtux'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:21.366506+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [paperclip] saving /pins/i
mages/000/000/004/original/GDT05_camera_lens3.png
←[33m2014-06-02T06:21:23.087200+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=POST pa
th=/pins host=arcane-shelf-3404.herokuapp.com request_id=4161c089-c9d8-4111-90bf
-4f4d43c3ec06 fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=4078ms status
=500 bytes=1754
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:22.992585+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Ser
ver Error in 3583ms
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:22.994508+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:22.994513+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/pins_con
troller.rb:22:in `create'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:22.994517+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:22.994511+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ArgumentError (missing req
uired :bucket option):
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:22.994515+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[33m2014-06-02T06:21:23.557093+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/favicon.ico host=arcane-shelf-3404.herokuapp.com request_id=7362fd76-f3a3-43c
c-9e15-9dc5b67c7646 fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms st
atus=304 bytes=133
←[33m2014-06-02T06:21:27.043612+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/ host=arcane-shelf-3404.herokuapp.com request_id=fa665a0f-e648-46c7-91e1-90dc
b9f707c9 fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=91ms status=200 by
tes=2820
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:26.958962+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 190.11
4.248.109 at 2014-06-02 06:21:26 +0000
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:27.011097+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (20.0ms)
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:27.031399+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 58ms (
Views: 45.2ms | ActiveRecord: 6.9ms)
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:26.973229+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:27.028535+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (9.7ms)
←[33m2014-06-02T06:21:28.866584+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/pins/new host=arcane-shelf-3404.herokuapp.com request_id=0a7fdeb0-f980-4238-a
0d2-ea2144baccea fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=134ms stat
us=304 bytes=887
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:28.743259+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/pins/new" fo
r 190.114.248.109 at 2014-06-02 06:21:28 +0000
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:28.835827+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/_form.html
.erb (34.4ms)
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:28.857782+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (16.6ms)
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:28.749705+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#new as HTML
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:28.839410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/new.html.e
rb within layouts/application (43.5ms)
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:28.858300+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 109ms
(Views: 68.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:33.993156+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd6.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:33.822304+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started POST "/pins" for 1
90.114.248.109 at 2014-06-02 06:21:33 +0000
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:33.826962+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#create as HTML
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:33.827030+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"??
?", "authenticity_token"=>"EMnpdVv9KK1Sz/kCL9X21W+6mfepM8/D+QFelQvmXXM=", "pin"=
>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbb4badc498 @tempfile=#<Tem
pfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140602-2-3jyqo2>, @original_filename="GDT05_camera len
s3.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; na
me=\"pin[image]\"; filename=\"GDT05_camera lens3.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/pn
g\r\n">, "description"=>"asdadasdasda"}, "commit"=>"Create Pin"}
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:33.869769+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-z
zqfd6.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:34.091066+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd6.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:34.194753+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd6.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:34.387242+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: convert '/tmp/f
85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd6.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "3
00x300>" '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd620140602-2-w9apg
o'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:34.936114+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd6.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:34.714299+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: file -b --mime
'/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd620140602-2-w9apgo'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:34.798542+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-z
zqfd6.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.007664+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd6.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.083964+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd6.png[0]'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.155921+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: convert '/tmp/f
85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd6.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "1
00x100>" '/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd620140602-2-tcs6x
q'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.336235+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: file -b --mime
'/tmp/f85a2368337734c012dda7e3c61bfb8920140602-2-zzqfd620140602-2-tcs6xq'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.400880+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Ser
ver Error in 1574ms
←[33m2014-06-02T06:21:35.408004+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=POST pa
th=/pins host=arcane-shelf-3404.herokuapp.com request_id=806524e8-55f9-4415-b36c
-ff49090c6bda fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1986ms status
=500 bytes=1754
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.406124+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ArgumentError (missing req
uired :bucket option):
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.406127+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.406118+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.397496+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [paperclip] saving /pins/i
mages/000/000/005/original/GDT05_camera_lens3.png
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.406126+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/pins_con
troller.rb:22:in `create'
←[36m2014-06-02T06:21:35.406128+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
```

Comment: Here `ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option)`

Answer (score 2):

> ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):

That's your error, and it's defined as a **`Paperclip`** problem.

The issue will be that you're trying to use the [`s3`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) connectivity in Paperclip, but have not defined the `bucket` option (which is [required](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3))

---

## Fix

There are two ways to fix this problem:

**1) Model**

As defined in the [Paperclip docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3), you can set the `bucket` option in your model:

```
#app/models/your_model.rb
has_attached_file :image,
        :styles => { :medium => "x300", :thumb => "x100" },
        :storage => :s3,
        :bucket => '******',
        :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS
```

**2) Config**

A far more robust way is to use the `config` files of your system to fix it. The way to do this is to use the `production.rb` file to define the bucket once:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
....
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    },
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
})
```

---

As you may be able to tell; both of these are from our current codebase, so should work. The only issue you may have is the `config` script might need tweaking. If you comment, I'll help

Comment: Hi! Is this "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" a general s3_host_name? or where do i check mine?

Comment: Sorry, this is for *our* server, as we're in Western Europe :) You don't need it, as it defaults to the US hostnames

Comment: I have added my answer

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

Write this in your production.rb

```
 config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```